# SP 2013 People search sort by Last Name

Tags: web-part, search-results, people-search

We have a SharePoint 2013 on premises intranet portal. I want to sort people search by first name and last name. I have set the Last Name property as sortable in central admin -> search schema settings and completed a full crawl.

In the search results webpart query builder i have selected first name and last name.

But when I test the results I get this error as shown below.

Any Suggestions?

[image]

[image]

ULS log

> Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry : Exceptions occurred when evaluating the flow.  Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException: Query lookup failed on 3 attempts. Remaining time is: 14.8437672 seconds. Giving up.     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithTryCatch(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.SubmitData(FlowExecutionInfo handle, InputData inputData, Stopwatch timer, String correlationId, Guid tenantId, String query, String flowName, Int32 queryTimeoutMillis)     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.ExecuteFlow(String flowName, InputData input, Int32 queryTimeoutMillis)    b9813c9d-d25b-404e-23cb-a5f278ee7b60
>
> [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 10/30/2015 09:28:53.77, Original Level: Verbose] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspxActivity boundary./LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/cf8b14f64a1144cc95d78bf2bc79890e-2-130904313830821156Process action 'http://tempuri.org/IImsService/Execute'.ProcessAction b9813c9d-d25b-404e-23cb-a5f278ee7b60
>   10/30/2015 09:28:53.94  w3wp.exe (0x1C04)                           0x5350  SharePoint Foundation           Service Connections             ev2x    High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] System.ServiceModel Resume: 131085 :   b9813c9d-d25b-404e-23cb-a5f278ee7b60